# what is the directory .virtualenvs? (was: ImportError: No module named django_cron, is my virtual environment set correct?)

Tags: python, django, cron, virtualenv, django-cron

I am trying to modify my virtual environment to add a new library (django-cron).  When I execute a pip list

```
(env_dili_py27)[todd@somewhere site-packages]$ pip list
Django (1.5.4)
django-common-helpers (0.6.0)
django-cron (0.3.3)
django-filter (0.7)
djangorestframework (2.3.8)
Markdown (2.3.1)
MySQL-python (1.2.4)
pip (1.4.1)
setuptools (0.9.8)
South (0.8.4)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
```

however the list of packages doesn't include djanago cron:

```
(env_dili_py27)[todd@somewhere python2.7]$ ls site-packages/ -l
total 448
drwxrwxr-x 17 todd todd   4096 Oct 19 08:54 django
drwxrwxr-x  2 todd todd   4096 Oct 19 08:54 Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg-info
drwxrwxr-x  2 todd todd   4096 Oct 19 08:56 django_filter-0.7-py2.7.egg-info
drwxrwxr-x  3 todd todd   4096 Oct 19 08:56 django_filters
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Oct 22 11:02 djangorestframework-2.3.8-py2.7.egg-info
-rw-rw-r--  1 todd todd    126 Jul 15  2013 easy_install.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 todd todd    340 Oct 19 08:28 easy_install.pyc
drwxrwxr-x  3 todd todd   4096 Oct 19 08:54 markdown
drwxrwxr-x  2 todd todd   4096 Oct 19 08:54 Markdown-2.3.1-py2.7.egg-info
drwxrwxr-x  2 todd todd   4096 Oct 19 08:28 _markerlib
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Oct 22 11:08 MySQLdb
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   2352 Oct 22 11:07 _mysql_exceptions.py
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   4555 Oct 22 11:08 _mysql_exceptions.pyc
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Oct 22 11:08 MySQL_python-1.2.4-py2.7.egg-info
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 139849 Oct 22 11:08 _mysql.so
drwxrwxr-x  6 todd todd   4096 Oct 19 08:28 pip
drwxrwxr-x  2 todd todd   4096 Oct 19 08:50 pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info
-rw-rw-r--  1 todd todd 101108 Jul 15  2013 pkg_resources.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 todd todd 114723 Oct 19 08:28 pkg_resources.pyc
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root   4096 Oct 22 11:02 rest_framework
drwxrwxr-x  5 todd todd   4096 Oct 19 08:28 setuptools
drwxrwxr-x  2 todd todd   4096 Oct 19 08:50 setuptools-0.9.8-py2.7.egg-info
```

In my settings.py i reference the django_cron library (as referenced: https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_cron',
    'rest_framework',
    'somewhereApp',
)
```

This is the exception log I am recieving:

```
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:05 2014] [info] [client 76.119.143.226] mod_wsgi (pid=10049, process='api.somewhere.com', application='api.somewhere.com|'): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/python.somewhere.com/somewhere/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error] Internal Server Error: /
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]   File "/home/todd/Envs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 92, in get_response
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]     response = middleware_method(request)
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]   File "/var/www/python.somewhere.com/somewhereApp/authentication.py", line 62, in process_request
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]     user = lookupUserById(userId)
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]   File "/var/www/python.somewhere.com/somewhereApp/authentication.py", line 15, in lookupUserById
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]     user = diliModels.User.objects.get(user_id=userId)
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]   File "/home/todd/Envs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 143, in get
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]     return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]   File "/home/todd/Envs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 395, in get
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]     clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]   File "/home/todd/Envs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 669, in filter
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]     return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]   File "/home/todd/Envs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 687, in _filter_or_exclude
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]     clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]   File "/home/todd/Envs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1271, in add_q
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]     can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]   File "/home/todd/Envs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1139, in add_filter
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]     process_extras=process_extras)
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]   File "/home/todd/Envs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1325, in setup_joins
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]     field, model, direct, m2m = opts.get_field_by_name(name)
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]   File "/home/todd/Envs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 351, in get_field_by_name
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]     cache = self.init_name_map()
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]   File "/home/todd/Envs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 380, in init_name_map
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]     for f, model in self.get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model():
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]   File "/home/todd/Envs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 469, in get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]     cache = self._fill_related_many_to_many_cache()
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]   File "/home/todd/Envs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 483, in _fill_related_many_to_many_cache
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]     for klass in get_models(only_installed=False):
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]   File "/home/todd/Envs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 197, in get_models
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]     self._populate()
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]   File "/home/todd/Envs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 72, in _populate
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]     self.load_app(app_name, True)
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]   File "/home/todd/Envs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 94, in load_app
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]     app_module = import_module(app_name)
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]   File "/home/todd/Envs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error]     __import__(name)
[Tue Feb 04 15:05:06 2014] [error] ImportError: No module named django_cron
```

---

I uninstalled django-cron and reinstalled it with verbose:

```
(env_dili_py27)[todd@somewhere site-packages]$ pip install django-cron -v
Downloading/unpacking django-cron
  Using version 0.3.3 (newest of versions: 0.3.3, 0.3.2, 0.3.1, 0.3.0, 0.2.9, 0.2.8, 0.2.7, 0.2.6, 0.2.5, 0.2.4, 0.2.3, 0.2.2, 0.2.1, 0.2, 0.1.2)
  Downloading django-cron-0.3.3.tar.gz
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/django-cron/django-cron-0.3.3.tar.gz#md5=586bed6c699e6b7f78eac2e83c8f0d6e (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django-cron/)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package django-cron
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/django_cron.egg-info
    writing requirements to pip-egg-info/django_cron.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing pip-egg-info/django_cron.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/django_cron.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/django_cron.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/django_cron.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/django_cron.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/django_cron.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Django>=1.5.0 in /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from django-cron)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): South>=0.8.1 in /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from django-cron)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django-common-helpers>=0.5.1 in /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from django-cron)
Installing collected packages: django-cron
  Running setup.py install for django-cron
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib
    creating build/lib/django_cron
    copying django_cron/timezone.py -> build/lib/django_cron
    copying django_cron/admin.py -> build/lib/django_cron
    copying django_cron/__init__.py -> build/lib/django_cron
    copying django_cron/test_settings.py -> build/lib/django_cron
    copying django_cron/tests.py -> build/lib/django_cron
    copying django_cron/cron.py -> build/lib/django_cron
    copying django_cron/models.py -> build/lib/django_cron
    creating build/lib/django_cron/migrations
    copying django_cron/migrations/__init__.py -> build/lib/django_cron/migrations
    copying django_cron/migrations/0001_initial.py -> build/lib/django_cron/migrations
    copying django_cron/migrations/0002_auto__add_field_cronjoblog_ran_at_time.py -> build/lib/django_cron/migrations
    copying django_cron/migrations/0003_auto__add_index_cronjoblog_end_time__add_index_cronjoblog_ran_at_time_.py -> build/lib/django_cron/migrations
    creating build/lib/django_cron/management
    copying django_cron/management/__init__.py -> build/lib/django_cron/management
    creating build/lib/django_cron/management/commands
    copying django_cron/management/commands/__init__.py -> build/lib/django_cron/management/commands
    copying django_cron/management/commands/runcrons.py -> build/lib/django_cron/management/commands
    running egg_info
    writing requirements to django_cron.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing django_cron.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to django_cron.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to django_cron.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'django_cron.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'django_cron.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running install_lib
    creating /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron
    copying build/lib/django_cron/timezone.py -> /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron
    copying build/lib/django_cron/admin.py -> /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron
    copying build/lib/django_cron/__init__.py -> /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron
    copying build/lib/django_cron/test_settings.py -> /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron
    creating /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron/migrations
    copying build/lib/django_cron/migrations/__init__.py -> /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron/migrations
    copying build/lib/django_cron/migrations/0001_initial.py -> /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron/migrations
    copying build/lib/django_cron/migrations/0002_auto__add_field_cronjoblog_ran_at_time.py -> /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron/migrations
    copying build/lib/django_cron/migrations/0003_auto__add_index_cronjoblog_end_time__add_index_cronjoblog_ran_at_time_.py -> /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron/migrations
    copying build/lib/django_cron/tests.py -> /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron
    copying build/lib/django_cron/cron.py -> /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron
    creating /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron/management
    copying build/lib/django_cron/management/__init__.py -> /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron/management
    creating /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron/management/commands
    copying build/lib/django_cron/management/commands/__init__.py -> /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron/management/commands
    copying build/lib/django_cron/management/commands/runcrons.py -> /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron/management/commands
    copying build/lib/django_cron/models.py -> /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron
    byte-compiling /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron/timezone.py to timezone.pyc
    byte-compiling /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron/admin.py to admin.pyc
    byte-compiling /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
    byte-compiling /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron/test_settings.py to test_settings.pyc
    byte-compiling /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron/migrations/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
    byte-compiling /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron/migrations/0001_initial.py to 0001_initial.pyc
    byte-compiling /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron/migrations/0002_auto__add_field_cronjoblog_ran_at_time.py to 0002_auto__add_field_cronjoblog_ran_at_time.pyc
    byte-compiling /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron/migrations/0003_auto__add_index_cronjoblog_end_time__add_index_cronjoblog_ran_at_time_.py to 0003_auto__add_index_cronjoblog_end_time__add_index_cronjoblog_ran_at_time_.pyc
    byte-compiling /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron/tests.py to tests.pyc
    byte-compiling /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron/cron.py to cron.pyc
    byte-compiling /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron/management/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
    byte-compiling /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron/management/commands/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
    byte-compiling /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron/management/commands/runcrons.py to runcrons.pyc
    byte-compiling /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron/models.py to models.pyc
    running install_egg_info
    Copying django_cron.egg-info to /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_cron-0.3.3-py2.7.egg-info
    running install_scripts
    writing list of installed files to '/tmp/pip-y2KoCb-record/install-record.txt'
Successfully installed django-cron
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/build...
(env_dili_py27)[todd@somewhere site-packages]$
```

AN ls

```
[todd@somewhere site-packages]$ ls  /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
django                                      django_filter-0.7-py2.7.egg-info          Markdown-2.3.1-py2.7.egg-info      _mysql.so                 setuptools
Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg-info                 django_filters                            _markerlib                         pip                       setuptools-0.9.8-py2.7.egg-info
django_common                               djangorestframework-2.3.8-py2.7.egg-info  MySQLdb                            pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info  south
django_common_helpers-0.6.0-py2.7.egg-info  easy_install.py                           _mysql_exceptions.py               pkg_resources.py          South-0.8.4-py2.7.egg-info
django_cron                                 easy_install.pyc                          _mysql_exceptions.pyc              pkg_resources.pyc
django_cron-0.3.3-py2.7.egg-info            markdown                                  MySQL_python-1.2.4-py2.7.egg-info  rest_framework
[todd@somewhere site-packages]$
```

So it is looking like it is installed now.  The only thing I did different was install with verbose command on...

---

Wait i think I see something. I am running django with python loaded from:

> /home/todd/Envs/env_dili_py27/...

but the library was installed  at

> /home/todd/.virtualenvs/env_dili_py27/...

What is **.virtualenvs** in the directory path (I am new to django/python and linux)?

Comment: Try to use verbose option on `pip install` to see more detail of how the lib is getting install, seems like it's not django-cron related problem

Comment: mariodev, thank you the verbose option gave some information which i think is to blame.  It is installing to .virtualenvs - what is  that directory, do you know?

Comment: Do you use `virtualenvwrapper`?

Comment: I had been, but then the folks at rackspace stepped up and "helped out" I wonder if that is the issue.  Maybe they didn't and that is why there are two separate areas?  How does that sound? Plausible?

Comment: Can you check your `.bashrc` for the venv paths..

Answer (score 0):

add app on the top of list

INSTALLED_APPS = [
# default django apps
'django_crontab',

## other apps

]

save settings.py and run server

if you are using in docker than docker-compose build
before docker-compose-up